# How pause/resume a mongodb cloud/atlas cluster from shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to follow the example on this page: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongocli/master/reference/atlas/cluster-pause#example

I start my shell first with the user password etc... and I've used it for other things, so I know that part is working.   Once I have the shell open, how do I pause/resume?

Part 2 - if CPU is 100%, will pause/resume effectively do what I would call a "restart" with other database servers?

I've tried the following:

```
MongoDB server version: 4.2.10
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
MongoDB Enterprise atlas-10ydpn-shard-0:PRIMARY> atlas cluster pause tdCluster0
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:6
MongoDB Enterprise atlas-10ydpn-shard-0:PRIMARY> cluster pause tdCluster0
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:8
MongoDB Enterprise atlas-10ydpn-shard-0:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: mongo shell is a different tool from mongocli. Read https://docs.mongodb.com/mongocli/master/ carefully.

Comment: The page you sent me to is about that, right.  Where does the "shell" fit in? I don't see it referenced on that page. Does it apply to Atlas?  I'm running mongo.exe like this: mongo "mongodb+srv://mycluster.otwxp.mongodb.net/mydbname" --username xxxx --password xxxx

Comment: Thanks Ok, I guess I was running shell, and I need to run client to run the commands in my question, is that what you are saying?  I see windows download zip here: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongocli/master/install#std-label-mcli-install